# What is the challenge/response method to securely authenticate with a Server without HTTPS (without sending out password)?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication

**What is the challenge/response method to securely authenticate with a Server without HTTPS (without sending out password)?**

I have an app (Javascript client) that connects over CORS (authenticate) to our backend which in turns will return a token containing the claim (JWT) over non-HTTPS. The REST is stateless so we do token-based and not have session at all.

When the client gets that token, (containing claim) it is added to the header for each request of the client and therefore the backend knows which User Id is doing that request and do the appropriate thing. So far this works for us. My concern is with the authentication process and with the security of each request.

To authenticate the clients sends out email and hashed password pair, however **I want to know if there's a more secure way even without using HTTPS for now.** I've read to not send the password but do a challenge/response, but what is the implementation of that idea?

And last question would be, even if we get around with the authentication process securely, **how about on each request which contains the token with claim can it be secured also?**

Comment: Nothing's secure if you're not using HTTPS.

Comment: You might want to take this to the Information Security stackexchange in any case.

Comment: You have to look at which solution solves which problem. HTTPS solves the problem of eavesdropping, challenge-response solves the problem of replay attacks. You probably want both. The way I like to think about it is: imagine you're using the wifi at a coffeeshop, can someone steal your session or perform actions in your name?

Comment: Your token system sounds an awful lot like non-RESTful state. Just because you changed the session id to a request header doesn't make it any more RESTful. REST is static, no dynamic tokens, no sessions.

Comment: What do you mean by "REST is static, no dynamic tokens, no sessions" @Halcyon ? Do you mean we should store tokens? Design experts suggest not to store tokens if that is the case.

Comment: You can have tokens in REST but not dynamic tokens since that implies state. Since your server seems to be the one dealing out tokens I assume it's a dynamic token (valid for the duration of a session). An example of a static token is an API-key (like Facebook has for their API).

Comment: @Halcyon There's no session in our Rest backend

Comment: You need HTTPs, if you plan to build a custom protocol which provides, server authentication, confidentiality and Integrity and others you will end up building a protocol similar to HTTPS

Comment: See: Challenge-Handshake Authentication Protocol ([CHAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no possible way to do this securely** without HTTPS. For your server to authenticate users, you need some kind of token (cookie, adding to requests like you have, etc.) However, the problem is that, without https, an eavesdropper can add javascript to your page. They can then capture the token and use it themself (stealing all the user's data), or modify it. If you want your product to be in any way secure, you need HTTPS.

Edit: I guess you could store some information about the device sending the request (user agent and such), and only allow the token to be used on that device. However, an attacker could just fake the user agent when they reuse the token, so this wouldn't be too hard to bypass.

Answer (score -1):

Challenge response is a mechanism to send passwords in non-clear way.

1°/ client and server must share a cyphering key : best is to manually add certificate on client but could be a little bit heavy. Another solution is to store the key only one time into localStorage.

2°/ client requests a challenge to server : this is a "phrase" generated by server

3°/ client concats its password with this "passphrase", ciphers and send response to server : Challenge => Response

4°/ server decrypt message, search and remove its passphrase to get password.

Comment: Not quite, I think what you are trying to describe in (2° -4°) is the Challenge-Handshake Authentication Protocol ([CHAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol#Working_cycle)).